# Matching a vector in another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a logical vector and I would like to find every index of the switches from FALSE to TRUE... ...in a one liner.
For instance :

```
logical = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
#return c(3, 6)
```

I thought about something like:

```
which(c(FALSE, TRUE)==logical)
```

But it is just not working. match is not doing any better. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

which(!logical & lead(logical))
# [1] 3 6
```

Comment: `which(tail(logical, -1) & !head(logical, -1))` would work without `dplyr`

Comment: @d.b Great solution. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

```
which(diff(logical) == 1)
[1] 3 6
```